# New Exterior Door Needs to be Trimmed - Slab vs. Pre-Hung, and Material

Tags: doors, woodworking, carpentry, steel, custom

I'm redoing a small exterior door that is not a standard size. Width is about 80", but height is closer to 77"-78". From what I can tell, the existing door was a simple slab door that was trimmed to fit.  I'm weighing my options and am considering either a wooden slab door, or, buying a pre-hung steel door and cutting it down.
I've done the job of cutting a pre-hung steel door many years ago as a helper and it worked out extremely well, and we went to like 75" on it and the door still looked great a decade later.

On my house, I'm debating if I want to get a wooden slab door, and rebuild the jamb/threshold/stop myself. A slab will allow me to trim the top and bottom slightly, where if its pre-hung I'll only be trimming the bottom. A lot of the solid exterior wooden doors these days are engineered with stiles and rails inside I assume so they aren't true solid wood. I'm not overly worried about the doors integrity based on elements though since its covered and not exposed to water, only cold/hot temperature.

Anyone trim down a door height to an unconventional size and have guidance on what door type (Slab and build all custom vs. trim a pre-hung door).

I'm hesitant to start this job since I'll need it done by the end of the day to close and secure the place by the end of the night. I may hire a carpenter friend who I know can hang slab doors, but unsure if he's ever trimmed down a pre-hung door.

Just looking for some general guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished a remodel on a rental with odd size doors that all were trashed. I built all the jambs and custom built the doors myself. Way too much time was spent on that. I wish I had bought prehung and trimmed down the doors.

Do some research. My partner found a door manufacturer that made pre hung or slab doors with 3 inches of wood on the top, bottom and sides.  He guaranteed you could trim off 1 1/2 inch from any edge and the door would still be good.
( He just found this a week too late! )
Shortening the frames is simple. Too much off a top or bottom means rebuilding part of a door.

Point is, before you decide, search outside the big box stores. A little more spent direct to a door specialist could save you a lot of time and headaches.
I now know where to go for my doors.

Personal preference is solid wood over steel, but I'm a guy that likes stained over painted.

Comment: Thanks @RMDman, that's helpful. Any idea who the manufacturer of those trimmable door was? This door is certain a custom job, whether it is pre-hung and we cut the lower part of the jamb and door, or get a slab and go full custom. Either way I'll need to cut this door past the typical limits unless I can find something like the door you are suggesting.

The door now may actually be a hollow core interior door and its actually help up quite well considering how old it is. It is not exposed to water or real elements other than cold, so that's why it probably did as well as it has.

Comment: @RocketManZ, The doors are manufactured and sold at a local facility near me in Tampa Fl.  They aren't sold nationwide.  You probably have something similar near you.

Answer (score 0):

While most prehung doors have hollow interior, they also have a solid frame.

Varying from model to model the solid frame part is about 2 or more inches.

You can use a stud finder to find yours.

You can cut it with fine tooth circular saw with a guide to get a straight cut from the top and bottom. I have cut a few without problems.

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes. It sounds like the doors at the big box stores that are wooden are engineered so I expect some type of voids inside. I have cut hollow interior doors and have blocked them. With the exterior door I'll want to retain the sweep mechanism so I'll need to re-attach that if I go pre-hung. Just thinking of the weather stripping and all I'm debating if it makes sense to modify a pre-hung, or just get a slab and go to town and rebuild the jamb and all.

Comment: "Engineered" exterior doors would normally be solid with no voids inside. But there could still be problems for a given door with cutting 40 mm or more off the bottom. It might weaken the frame or be strange in appearance.